# How to get Excel cell font color RGB using Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

`getStyle().getFont(workbook).getColor()` returns a short. How do I get RGB value of the color?

BTW,

```
palette.getColor(style.getFont(this.book).getColor()).getTriplet()
```

does not always work (null pointer exception happens sometimes). maybe I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have figured it out. When a cell is using default color (black usually), the default color does not exist in color palette.

Here's a working example:

```
final HSSFColor foreColor = palette.getColor(style.getFont(this.book).getColor());
if (foreColor != null) {
    final short[] foreRGB = foreColor.getTriplet();
    if (foreRGB[0] != 0 || foreRGB[1] != 0 || foreRGB[2] != 0) {
        out.append("color: rgb(").append(foreRGB[0]).append(',').append(foreRGB[1]).append(',').append(foreRGB[2]).append(");");
    }
}
```